# Index Match 2 values with Address issues

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-2010, match

I'm trying to create a formula that doesn't have too many hardcoded values and uses references to return a value.

I have this formula working:
`{=INDEX(Calculations!$B$13:$Q$43,MATCH(1,(Calculations!$C$13:$C$43='Client Report'!$B$19)*(Calculations!$B$13:$B$43='Client Report'!B20),0),8)}`

However I need to remove the 'Client Report'!$B$19 part and have it dynamically reference, for this I've used the below, where A20 is the cell I want my formula to be in.

`=ADDRESS(ROW(A20)-A20,2,1,1,"Client Report")`

But when I include this line I receive the #N/A error, does anybody have any ideas as to resolve this?

I have a suspicion that the Match formula won't allow me to add in a formula as a reference.

Comment: You need to wrap any text representation of a cell address in `INDIRECT` in order to change it to a functional cell address. e.g. not `="A1"` but `=INDIRECT("A!")` so replace `'Client Report'!$B$19` with `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(A20)-A20,2,1,1,"Client Report"))`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Jeeped, but that doesn't fix the #N/A. Using your suggestion on it's own I get the value of the cell I'm after (A19), however when it is in the main formula it doesn't work, which is what led me to think it might be because the MATCH function doesn't allow further calculations?

Comment: I suspect you may be right in that the overlaying *array processing* may be fouling up the `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(...))` functions. Cal you switch to another method such as `OFFSET('Client Report'!$A$20,-A20,1)`?

Comment: Perfect! For some reason I ruled out OFFSET but it's done the trick! Thanks for your help Jeeped!